# Visit Visa Documents Required to Visit Boyfriend in Czech Republic

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, czech-republic, invitation-letters

I am Tushar and I am in a gay relationship with a Czech citizen. He visited me in India 4 times. I want to visit him for 10 days in Czech Republic this year.

History: Last year I applied for visa. On cover letter I mentioned that He is my friend and he was in India, so he is inviting me to czech. I attached pozvani letter as well. on pozvani letter it was mentioned that I will visit him for not more than 90 days and maximum by 31st dec 2019. But I applied visa for 10 days.
I attached our photos as a friend and his national identity card. My visa got rejected by stating that my intention to leave the territory of member states before visa expiry is not sure.

Current situation: Now, I want to apply again. I want to tell the truth that we are dating. I asked a person who got visa from Czech embassy to visit his girlfriend without pozvani letter. His girlfriend gave him a simple invitation letter written by her and a sponsorship letter, where it was mentioned that she will provide accommodation and food. So How should I proceed now?

I want to write in cover letter that we are boyfriends, and some detail of our relationship, purpose of visit etc. and all other documents like my bank statement, salary slips, income tax return for 2 years, insurance etc.

From his side:
Should my boyfriend give me pozvani letter or write a simple invitation letter?
His copy passport? His visa to India multiple times. our photos. He doesnt have a rent agreement from his landlord, so is it okay to provide passport and his identity card as proof of accommodation?

My profile: I am working in a good company and I earn a very good salary.

Guys, please guide us if you really understand this matter.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No point applying again, no matter how much you explain about the relationship, if you don’t satisfy the Czech authorities that you will return to India. What ties do you have that would compel you to return eg job, dependent family?

Comment: I mentioned last time about my good job and high salary as well.

Comment: ‘Mentioned’ or ‘provided evidence’ about your job? Do you have a previous travel history? If not, you’ll probably be better building up one before you reapply, maybe by visiting country(ies) with your boyfriend where entry criteria are less strict than for the Schengen zone. You need to convince the authorities that you are not at risk of overstaying or illegal working.

Comment: It would probably be easier to understand your question if you keep to English. Not many readers here understand Czech and will know what a pozvání is.

Comment: pozvání means invitation. And that is what he must apply for in the Czech Republic. If granted, you must provide the proper information to convince the consulate that you will be returning when making the visa application.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the first application was that they doubted you would actually leave at the end of the trip. If you were to re-apply you need to provide as much solid evidence as possible to assure their worries you will not stay in the country after your visit.

You said you mentioned your job last time, but you need to be very clear about it, show your contract/proof that you work there, get a letter from your employer stating that you're allowed the specified dates off work to go on to this trip, and that you'll then be expected back to continue your job.

Do you own any property/pay rent? If so, show proof of this and state your intention to go back and continue living there as you have signed a set length of time on the lease. Do you support anyone else financially/care for anyone? If so provide proof of this too, and who will be covering this whilst you are gone. Do you have strong community ties, if so provide any proof possible of these too.

Do you have any travel history, other trips that you have been on that you can show to display your intentions to return back to India after leaving? If you have none, try and take some small trips to the cheapest places you can find, build up a history of travelling reliably as this will help your case. Provide proof of these trips and your ability to keep to the set dates you intended to.

Any proof your partner can provide would help, if he has no rental agreement with his landlord is he able to ask them to write a letter stating you are allowed to visit for 10 days, and 10 days only, this way it again highlights that you won't be able to stay longer. If he will be purchasing your food whilst you visit does he have proof that he can do so?

Getting a pozvani letter won't hurt your application, and at only 300CZK it is relatively well priced to get an official document stating your invitation, but it won't guarantee that they will grant the application by itself, you still need the proof detailed above.

As for changing what you stated on your initial application from friend to boyfriend, I can't answer that as it would be speculation/opinion and that question better suits someone who works for their visa office. But, it is easier to be honest and upfront as they will react far worse if they then find this out themselves later on.

Good luck, I hope it all works out! In the meantime, is there a seperate middle country you guys could meet up in, allowing you to see each other and to build your travel history?